# ajax jquery code does not work on android -Phonegap-

Tags: android, jquery, ios, ajax, phonegap

I created a mobile application using the phonegap framework and it worked well in ios and android but the problem is that the ajax jquery code does not work on android

Thank you for helping me find a solution

ajax jquery code

```
$ (document) .ready (function () {
$ .Ajax ({
url: "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"
}). then (function (data) {
. $ ( '. Greeting-id') append (data.id);
. $ ( '. Greeting-content') append (data.content);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how is this failing in Android? Does not seem to be legal code in terms of Javascript language syntax.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working on app which wants to access the internet, you need to add extra permission in androidManifest.xml else your application won’t be able to access the internet.
So you need to put below code in AndroidManifest.xml file to access the internet in your app.

Add Below permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.
Step 1 :

```
Go to app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml.
```

Step 2 :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```