# How do I request permissions for my PhoneGap project built using PhoneGap Build?

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap

I am trying to get started with Phonegap and Phonegap Build to create a html/jquery based Android app.  Currently my app consists of one single html page that allows you to enter two numbers, those numbers are sent out to my server, and the response is displayed on screen.  Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
            <title>PoC</title>
            <script src="JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="JS/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script language="javascript" src="JS/date.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css">

            <script>
                function doCalc() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://nightscapecreations.com/test.cfc?method=multNums&thisNum=" + $('#thisNum').val() + "&multBy=" + $('#multBy').val()
                    }).done(function( data ) {
                        data    = data.trim();
                        if ($.isNumeric(data)) {
                            $('#resultDiv').html(data); 
                        } else {
                            $('#resultDiv').html(data);
                        }
                    })
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
            This is a test.  Here, multiply some numbers:

            <input id="thisNum" placeholder="5" onChange="doCalc();"> x
            <input id="multBy" placeholder="3" onChange="doCalc();">
            =
            <div id="resultDiv">

            </div>

            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="doCalc();" style="width:150px;">
        </body>
    </html>
```

Just a very messy test to see how this whole thing works.  This functions when opened on a browser, or when run through the Phonegap app.  However, when I upload this to Phonegap Build, download the apk, copy it to the device, and install it there, the div fails to populate.

I looked at my app and was surprised to see it listed with no permissions.  I suspect this is the cause of the failure; the app cannot access the internet and so cannot get a response back from its ajax call.  This would also explain why PB's Weinre debugging shows no targets.  However, no matter what I do I cannot figure out how to get PB to assign permissions.

This is my current config:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="com.nightscapecreations.test"
            version="1.0.0"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
            xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
        <name>Test</name>
        <description>
            A PoC app
        </description>
        <author email="xxxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
            My Name
        </author>
        <content src="index.html" />

        <access origin="*" />
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
        <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
        <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
        <platform name="android">
          <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="ios">
          <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
          <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        </platform>

        <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
        <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
        <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
        <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    </widget>
```

There's a lot in there because I've been going through countless iterations of trial and error with stuff pulled from all over SO and various blogs.  I have tried with and without the preference tags, the feature tag, the plugin tag, and much more, but no permissions are ever requested by the app.

I also tried adding a security policy as suggested in another post, but without success:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="default-src *; 
               style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
               script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

How do I insure that my app has sufficient privileges to get data from my server?

Comment: Try to add plugin  whitelist https://stackoverflow.com/a/56882276/8603198

Comment: I hope this ans helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56407428/ajax-jquery-code-does-not-work-on-android-phonegap/56438226#56438226